# React+Typescript conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, conditional-statements, rendering, tsx

I want to create an option for every single profile that I have. I checked and I do have a profile so the profiles array is not empty and profile.profilename isn't undefined. It just doesn't render.

What i see:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSjoJ.png)

```
<div className="col-4">
   <select name="profile" className="billingSelector">
         <option>Billing profile</option>
             {(getProfiles() as any).forEach((profile:Profile) => {
                  <option>{profile.profileName}</option>
              })}
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What does `getProfiles()` return? Why `as any`?

Comment: as any is irrelevant, i was just trying to fix it.
getProfiles() return a Profile array so i am getting all of its elements.
i removed `as any` from the code

Comment: Is it by any chance async? What does `console.log(getProfiles())` print?

Comment: `console.log(getProfiles())` prints out the array. It has one element which is the profile that I want to show on screen.

Comment: `[p]
0: p {profileName: "test profile #1", firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", postalCode: "29223", city: "Celle", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `foreach`.

There is a difference. Map returns list, foreach - not.

More info on that:

[Array.prototype.forEach() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

[Array.prototype.map() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I used map instead of foreach and i removed curly braces and used regular ones.

```
<select name="profile" className="billingSelector">
   <option>Billing profile</option>
   {getProfiles().map((profile:Profile)=> (
        <option key={profile.profileName}>{profile.profileName}</option>
   ))}       
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of foreach can you please try map ? E.g

getProfiles().map((profile, index) => (  {profile.profileName}));